# If every non-empty subset of a totally ordered set $Y$ has both a minimum and a maximum, then show that $Y$ is finite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

This is the question statement: Let $Y$ be a totally ordered set such that every non-empty subset of $Y$ has both a minimum and a maximum. Show that $Y$ is finite.

I am pretty confused as to how do I even approach this question. Any help would be nice.

edit: Please provide any hints/help considering the fact that this is my first rigorous mathematical course, and I have started from scratch, the ZFC axioms. So, please only use definitions of totally ordered sets, max/min element etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y\in Y$. If $y$ is the maximum of $Y$, let $\phi(y) = y$. If not, let $\phi(y) := \min \{x \in Y \ \vert \ y < x\}$.

Let $z_0$ be the minimum of $Y$. Define, inductively, the sequence $(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ by $\forall n, \ z_{n+1} = \phi(z_n)$.

Consider $Z := \{z_n \ \vert \ n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

1. Let $k$ be the integer such that $z_k$ is the maximum of $Z$. Prove that $\phi(z_k) = z_k$.
2. Prove that $z_k$ is the maximum of $Y$.
3. Prove that $Z$ is finite.
4. Let $y\in Y$. Prove that $y\in Z$. *Hint: if $y$ isn’t the minimum of $Y$, consider $z:= \max \{x\in Z \ \vert \ x < \min\{t\in Z \ \vert \ y\leq t\}\}$. Prove that $y=\phi(z)$.*

Comment: Max element will be some $z_{k}, k\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t, $z_k=\text{Max}(Y)$, and we would have $Z=Y$. Now, since there is a bijection between sets $Z\text{and}\{1,2,\cdots,k\}$, set 
 $Z$ and hence set $Y$ is finite. Does this look fine?

Comment: It depends on how rigourous your proof is expected to be. It is correct but it would probably be worth for you to write it in more detail.

Comment: Oh, which part exactly ? I'm all in for rigor.

Comment: Why should the maximum of $Z$ be also the maximum of $Y$? And how do you deduce that $Z=Y$?

Comment: I added more hints.

Comment: Are the hints meant to be proved in chronological order ?

Comment: Yes, but feel free to treat them in any order you like.

Comment: I had just another doubt. I proved 1-3, but for 4, how are you defining z := with an expression, that already has z inside it ?

Comment: It’s because I made a mistake.